# Why doesnt my migration plugin run?

Tags: nodes, migrations

[image]I made a plugin to add the alias to my node migration, using the instructions here https://www.calebthorne.com/blog/drupal/2016/07/16/drupal-8-migrate-pathauto

but i tried to put a drush break point and it never runs .  How do i get this plugin to run during the migration?  this is the plugin code below .  and the yml is as follows:

```
id: migd8_node_blog
label: Custom node migration from Drupal 7
migration_group: cncs
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migd8_node_blog
source:
 plugin: d7_node
 node_type: blog_entry
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  bundle: blog_entry
process:
  type: 
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: blog_entry
  'path/alias': alias
```

migd8_node_blog/src/Plugin/migrate/source/Node.php

```
<?php
     
    /**
     * @file
     * Contains \Drupal\migd8_node_blog\Plugin\migrate\source\Node.
     */
     
    namespace Drupal\migd8_node_blog\Plugin\migrate\source;
     
    use Drupal\migrate\Row;
    use Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\source\d7\Node as D7Node;
    
    /**
     * Custom node source including url aliases.
     *
     * @MigrateSource(
     *   id = "migd8_node_blog"
     * )
     */
    class Node extends D7Node {
    
      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public function fields() {
        return ['alias' => $this->t('Path alias')] + parent::fields();
      }
    
      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
        // Include path alias.
        $nid = $row->getSourceProperty('nid');
        drush_print_r($nid);
        $query = $this->select('url_alias', 'ua')
          ->fields('ua', ['alias']);
        $query->condition('ua.source', 'node/' . $nid);
        $alias = $query->execute()->fetchField();
        if (!empty($alias)) {
          $row->setSourceProperty('alias', '/' . $alias);
        }
        return parent::prepareRow($row);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by uninstalling and reinstalling the module and deleting the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Article is correct, just noticed that it's a **source** plugin and not a process plugin.

Change yours to

```
id: migd8_node_blog
label: Custom node migration from Drupal 7
migration_group: cncs
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migd8_node_blog

source:
 plugin: migd8_node_blog_node # use custom node source plugin
 node_type: blog_entry

destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  bundle: blog_entry

process:
  nid: nid
  type: type
  'path/pathauto':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0 # Disable pathauto.
  'path/alias': alias
```

And

```
/**
 * Custom node source including url aliases.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "migd8_node_blog_node"
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Like I said, change it to `migd8_node`. It might clash since you're already using `migd8_node_blog` as a migration ID, on line 1 of your yml file.

Comment: i did that now i get Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "migd8_node" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for          [error]
Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigratePluginManager are: addressfield, block_plugin_id, etc.

Comment: Did you flush cache?

Comment: yes i did drush cr several times

Comment: My bad, I had your module name wrong, fixed.

Comment: @Diana Your module's name is `migd8_node_blog`, right? I'm assuming that based on the `namespace`.

Comment: yes that is the name of the module .  but now i get Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "migd8_node_blog_node" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for                   [error]
Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigratePluginManager are: addressfield, block_plugin_id, block_region, block_settings, block_theme, block_visibility,
f

Comment: Did you place the Node.php file that you created in the `migd8_node_blog/src/Plugin/migrate/source/` folder?

Comment: yes that is exactly where it is.

Comment: @Diana updated the answer, should work now 

Comment: i changed it to use the source as above , still get the same error source:
 plugin: migd8_node_blog_node # use custom source plugin
 node_type: blog_entry

Comment: still getting Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "migd8_node_blog_node" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for

Comment: Send me a screenshot of your module's folder structure, something is off. Worked fine for me.

Comment: i just added the correct screen shot .

Comment: i cleared cache again and imported again and it works now with your last suggestion. thanks