# why am i getting a Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: when the plugin does exist?

Tags: migrations, plugins

I wrote a custom source plugin and put it in migd8_node_blog/src/Plugin/migrate/source/Node.php
with

```
<?php
 
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\migd8_node_blog\Plugin\migrate\source\Node.
 */
 
namespace Drupal\migd8_node_blog\Plugin\migrate\source;
 
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\source\d7\Node as D7Node;

    /**
     * Custom node source including url aliases.
     *
     * @MigrateSource(
     *   id = "migd8_node_blog_node"
     * )
     */
    
    class Node extends D7Node {
```

but i keep getting this error when i run drush mim migd8_node_blog Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "migd8_node_blog_node" plugin does not exist.
even after flushing the cache and reinstalling the module.

Comment: Did you add a correct namespace matching the machine name of your module?

Comment: yes namespace Drupal\migd8_node_blog\Plugin\migrate\source;

Comment: And the casing's right on the file/class names? For `node.php` the class would be `node`, not `Node`, for example. Or if the class is `Node` the filename needs to be `Node.php` depending on how you want to look at it

Comment: yes class Node extends D7Node { the file name is Node.php

Comment: use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\source\d7\Node as D7Node;

Comment: You should put all the extra information (and fix the filename) in the question, it won't be useful in the comments

Comment: ive done that now

Comment: Two last things that I'd add - firstly what are you running to get the error (presumably `drush mim` but being explicit is good), and I'd confirm that the path you've provided to the file is relative to `module/src`. Hopefully after that the downvoters will revisit and reconsider, as it would then be a good question IMO

Comment: when i disabled and reenabled the module and deleted the configuration it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> after flushing the cache and **reinstalling the module**

Check that the module is indeed installed at `/admin/modules`, if it's not, it's due to a [migrate tools bug](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus/issues/2822737). Perhaps you deleted the part

```
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migd8_node_blog
```

that you have in [your other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297666/why-doesnt-my-migration-plugin-run), which fixes the reinstall bug if you have it before you install the module.

But if you installed it without the above code, you'll have to run this code **once/one time only**, and it will allow you to install again as this code removes the stuck configuration.

```
  $module_path = DRUPAL_ROOT . base_path() . drupal_get_path('module', 'migd8_node_blog') . '/config/install';

  $configs = array();
  $files = file_scan_directory($module_path, '/migrate_plus/');
  if ($files) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $configs[] = $file->name;
    }
    // Delete each config using configFactory.
    foreach ($configs as $config_name) {
     \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable($config_name)->delete();
    }

    return TRUE;
  }
```

---

If the modue is indeed installed, then the issue is due to you trying to assign `migd8_node_blog_node` as a plugin under the wrong key.

Since this is a **source** plugin and should be used only be used under `source:` and not/never under `process:` or any other key. See [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297672/27710).

Comment: id: migd8_node_blog
label: Custom node migration from Drupal 7
migration_group: cncs
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migd8_node_blog_node
source:
 plugin: migd8_node_blog_node 
 node_type: blog_entry
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  bundle: blog

Comment: okay as in the previous question after uniinstalling and reinsalling the module and deleting the configuration it finally worked.